# What is this "flap-like" thing on the back of the F-15?

Tags: landing, aircraft-systems, jet, fighter, f-15

I saw an image of an F-15 landing. What is that flap-like thing in the top of the plane in this picture? I couldn't find it on any other pictures or drawings of this aircraft.

[image: f15 flap thing]

Comment: That's an air brake. The f-35 has one also and a few other jets have them too. Designed to slow the aircraft down even more with the addition of flaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a speed brake (air brake). Here is a closeup of it.

[image: Speed brake]

Image from aero-cafe.com

It is usually used reducing speed landing (approach). It is also used for other functions- to slow down quickly at high speeds and to prevent too much speed buildup in a dive.

This image shows it being used during approach.

[image: F-15 speed brake]

"[F-15A 21st TFW landing with extended speed brake 1984](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:F-15A_21st_TFW_landing_with_extended_speed_brake_1984.JPEG#/media/File:F-15A_21st_TFW_landing_with_extended_speed_brake_1984.JPEG)" by SSgt. K. Vail, USAF - U.S. DefenseImagery photo VIRIN: DF-ST-85-11671. Licensed under Public Domain via [Wikimedia Commons](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

Similar airbrakes are also found in other aircraft, notably the Su 27 and its derivatives.

[image: Su 27 airbrakes]

Image from aerospaceweb.org

Comment: The F/A-18 and the F-35 have speedbrakes as well, to add a few more aircraft with those to the list.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann only the F/A-18 A-D has the speed brake, it was deleted for the E, F and G.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann I'm not sure about speedbrakes in F35. You're probably talking about the covers of vertical fan?

Comment: @aeroalias The A and C versions of the F-35 don't have a lift fan but the brake is still there, the B version does have a lift fan and the cover is used as a brake as well.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann hmmm...  My understanding is that the [speed brakes of F35 operate by deflection of control surfaces](http://www.codeonemagazine.com/article.html?item_id=33).

Comment: @Moo Doesn't the F/A-18E Super Hornet has speed brakes too? The two things that deploy over the wings?

Comment: if they are over the wings, and they dump lift as well as create drag, they are called *spoilers*.

Answer (score 5):

It's an air brake, also called a speedbrake.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_brake_(aeronautics)

Another view of an F-15 landing with the speed brake open:
[image: Eagle landing]
<sup>Source: Wikipedia, click to embiggen</sup>